# Extract msu files from Windows 10 22H2 ISO

Tags: powershell, iso-image, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to generate msu files from Windows 10 22H2 ISO file. I couldn't find any on that in Google so I believe that this make no sense.
Is there any other way to generate msu files since Microsoft does not offer them for 22H2?

I was able to generate WIM file from ISO using the following powershell code

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Windows_Versions\Windows_22H2.iso"
(Get-DiskImage "C:\Windows_Versions\Windows_22H2.iso" | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:F:\sources\install.esd
dism /export-image /SourceImageFile:F:\sources\install.esd /SourceIndex:6 /DestinationImageFile:C:\Windows_Versions\install.wim /Compress:max /CheckIntegrity
```

The reason I need msu files is because I am using PDQ to deploy updates and upgrades. PDQ allows to upgrade Windows version with msu files on multiple computers.

Comment: I am curious as to why you need this. I download a Windows ISO, use it to install (VM) or Repair (physical box) and then delete it. I do not care about the contents of the ISO file.

Comment: MSU files are installed by Windows Update. People with good intentions shouldn't be messing with these files.

Comment: Updating my question for explaining the reason

Comment: Thanks.  The situations I am familiar with use WSUS for updating workstations.

Comment: Thank you. We have lot of issues with WSUS on Server 2016 and it requires time to spent on it. I thought there is a solution to get msu somehow.

Comment: Are you trying to extract an MSU or generate one? Your question, though it is answered, is not clear. Without understanding the question, the answer is not useful to others.

Comment: @music2myear, I am trying to generate msu from 22H2 ISO or any other way.

Comment: Use the EDIT button and make the question itself clear. Comments do more improve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSU files are to be installed by Windows Update.
The best place to find them is in the
[Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)
that should contain just about any MSU file ever released.

Some MSU files may be found *inside* an ISO, but generally an ISO
contains an entire product to be wholly installed and can't be
converted into an MSU file.

Anyway, you can't generate these files yourself, as they are
signed with Microsoft's code certificate that you don't
(and won't) have.